# Replacing BCP utility with microservice

Tags: python, java, c#, webapi, flask-restful

My team want to implement a ASP.NET CORE Web API based micro service with a plan to replace [bulk copy program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) utility. Currently we are using BCP utility to return 200,000 rows with 30 columns. The data is returned in csv format.

We created a restful endpoint and using ADO.NET we are connecting to SQL server to extract same volume of data. Here is the code:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                string oString = "Select * from Employees where runid = 1";
                SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
                  
                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (oReader.Read())
                    {    
                        //Read data here                    
                    }

               }
         }
```

With this code, I am getting memory exceptions..

What is the best way to fix this issue considering in future I will get request to return higher volume of data with more users making simultaneous request.  **I am open to implementing this solution using C#, Java, Python or NodeJs.**

Comment: it might be too much to do all in one hit by a small microservice instance. maybe worth looking at options to break it apart into smaller batches or streaming through the file instead of opening it all in memory. https://aws.amazon.com/glue/ AWS Glue suggests that it has ETL functionality. Maybe that could be a good candidate for you. Theres a lot of articles for migrating data into the cloud too which might have some good patterns or concepts that you can copy... Or the other thing I would suggest is if you can change the entire solution to replicate in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

The following code streams the data directly from the database, so it should be quite memory efficient and performant. It is using the Sylvan Csv library functionality to create csv records directly from the SqlDataReader.

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
    using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
    using Sylvan.Data.Csv;

    ...

    [HttpGet(Name = "Get")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new FileCallbackResult("text/csv", async (outputStream, _) =>
        {
            using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration["ConnectionStrings"]))
            {
                var cmdText = "Select * from Employees where runid = 1";
                var command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, myConnection);

                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader oReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
                    var csvDataWriter = CsvDataWriter.Create(streamWriter);
                    await csvDataWriter.WriteAsync(oReader);
                } 
            }
        })
        {
            FileDownloadName = "employees.csv"
        };
    }
```

FileCallbackResult is from: https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/AsyncDynamicZip/blob/net6-ziparchive/Example/src/WebApplication/FileCallbackResult.cs

You can read about it here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html